# Creating constant slope DEM using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, arcgis-9.3, spatial-analyst

I wanted to create a DEM of constant slope say 1/3000.

How can I proceed in ArcGIS Desktop 9.3?

The area may be 1000m x 1000m or any other as per convenience.

Answer (score 7):

A solution to this is discussed on the ESRI forum [here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=995&t=268888#829193):

> Every planar surface has a simple formula, Jesse, in the form
>
> (something)*x + (something else)*y + (constant).
>
> In the Raster Calculator, x is $$XMap and y is $$YMap. The trick is
>   figuring out the coefficients. Often you want to specify a plane in
>   terms of its slope (s), aspect (a), and height at some given point
>   ("base elevation"). Its equation will be in the form
>
> -tan(a)*sin(s)*[x] - tan(a)*cos(s)*[y] + (constant).
>
> To work out that constant, plug in the coordinates where you know the
>   base elevation, say (x0, y0), and then adjust the constant to make it
>   work out. This produces the formula
>
> Base elevation + tan(a)*sin(s)*[x0] + tan(a)*cos(s)*[y0] = constant.
>
> For example, to produce a plane sloping s=30 degrees with an
>   northeastern aspect a=45 degrees, compute
>
> tan(a) = tan(45 degrees) = 1  sin(s) = sin(30 degrees) = 1/2  cos(s) =
>   cos(30 degrees) = Sqrt(3)/2 = about 0.866.
>
> Therefore the plane's height will be in the form
>
> $$XMap * (-0.5) - $$YMap * (0.866) + (constant)
>
> and you can work out the constant as described. (The Raster Calculator
>   will be REALLY picky about whether you use decimals and where you put
>   spaces, so watch out! Use an expression as close as possible to this
>   one.)
>
> As a double check, you can compute the slope and aspect of your
>   surface after you have generated it. Each should be approximately
>   constant to about five decimal places and equal to what you intended.
>
> The most common error made in ArcGIS is to compute the trig functions
>   using radians instead of degrees, because ArcGIS uses sometimes one
>   and sometimes the other. Because this is so quick and easy to do,
>   first reproduce the example here so you know you have your angular
>   units correct, then generate the plane you really want.
>
> --Bill Huber

You can take the logic and work it up into a Python script. Some useful discussion and links are found from this [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008DT2&returnUrl=%2Fapex%2FideaList%3Fc%3D09a300000004xET%26category%3DArcGIS%2BDesktop%2BExtensions%26p%3D3%26sort%3Dtop), according to which the $$XMAP were special variables not available after 9.3.1.